# Promise issues in typescript

Tags: typescript, web-audio-api, es6-promise

I've been experimenting Web Audio API with typescript. I'm in the process of creating an `AudioDownloader` class that downloads the audio data for a single or multiple audio files and returns a single or array of promises. In the case of downloading multiple audio files I don't want the `Promise.all` to get failed because of a single failure so I used a method called `reflect` (which I borrowed from net).

For some reason, the typescript compilation fails in the `download` method due to mismatch in return type. I've been trying to sort this out for last two days with no luck. I really don't understand what mistake I'm doing here. Can someone please help?

```
class PromiseResult<T> {
    value: T;
    error?: any;
    status: PromiseStatus;
}

enum PromiseStatus {
    Resolved,
    Rejected
}

function reflect<T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<PromiseResult<T>> {
    return promise.then(v => {
        return { status: PromiseStatus.Resolved, value: v };
    }, e => {
        return { status: PromiseStatus.Rejected, error: e }
    });
}

type AudioDownloadResult = PromiseResult<AudioBuffer>;

class AudioDownloader {

    private readonly context: AudioContext;

    constructor(context: AudioContext) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    download(urls: string | Array<string>): Promise<AudioDownloadResult | Array<AudioDownloadResult>> {
        if (typeof urls === 'string') {
            return reflect(this.downloadOne(urls as string));
        }

        return Promise.all((<Array<string>>urls).map(this.downloadOne).map(reflect));
    }

    private downloadOne(url: string): Promise<AudioDownloadResult> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', url, true);
            req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            req.addEventListener('load', () => {
                this.context.decodeAudioData(req.response).then(buffer => {
                    resolve(buffer);
                }, reject);
            }, false);
            req.addEventListener('error', reject, false);
            req.send();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the issue in the code the return type of `downloadOne` method should `Promise<AudioBuffer>` not `Promise<AudioDownloadResult>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor functions a bit and get it to work as expected by doing so:

```
class PromiseResult<T> {
    value: T;
    error?: any;
    status: PromiseStatus;
}

enum PromiseStatus {
    Resolved,
    Rejected
}

type AudioDownloadResult = PromiseResult<AudioBuffer>;

class AudioDownloader {

    private readonly context: AudioContext;

    constructor(context: AudioContext) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    async download(urls: string | Array<string>): Promise<AudioDownloadResult | Array<AudioDownloadResult>>
    {
      try
      {
        if (typeof urls === 'string')
        {
            return await this.downloadOne(urls as string);
        }

        let arr: AudioDownloadResult[] = [];
        for (let url of urls)
        {
          arr.push(await this.downloadOne(url));
        }

        return arr;
      }
      catch (err)
      {
        return { status: PromiseStatus.Rejected, error: err } as AudioDownloadResult;
      }
    }

    private downloadOne(url: string): Promise<AudioDownloadResult> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', url, true);
            req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            req.addEventListener('load', () => {
                this.context.decodeAudioData(req.response).then(buffer => {
                    resolve(buffer);
                }, reject);
            }, false);
            req.addEventListener('error', reject, false);
            req.send();
        });
    }
}
```

I have not tested it - but this should do the job.

Comment: If any of the audio fails to download does the other promises resolve in the above code?

Comment: The above code is not working as expected. If one download fails then it straightly comes to catch block.

Comment: Its very easy to alter its behavior to make it work like you need: just wrap `arr.push(await this.downloadOne(url));` with try/catch to allow loop to continue

Comment: Can we able to use arrow function instead of for loop?